# Handler or AsyncTask for Delayed Execution and UI updating in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler

I want to call a background task, 200ms after every touch event. At the end of the execution of the background task, I want to update the UI. There seem to be two possible approaches to do this - Handler and ASyncTask. Using handler I can call postDelayed for delayed execution and sendMessage() for UI update. With AsyncTask I can use a timer for delayed execution and onPostExecute for UI update. Which of these method will be better in terms of efficiency? I want the UI updates to be immediate after the task has executed and I read somewhere that Handler might not be best for that.

Comment: "I want to call a background task, 200ms after every touch event" -- there are lots of touch events, so this may not be sensible. "I want the UI updates to be immediate after the task has executed" -- whether those updates are "immediate" depends on what the main application thread is doing. `AsyncTask` *uses* `Handler`, and so from this standpoint, they will be similarly "immediate".

Comment: It's a keyboard and on every touchup from a key, I need to process the data and modify the EditText.

Comment: I am not aware that input method editors use the techniques that you are proposing.

Comment: Ya, not an IME ..just a grid of keys (buttons).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) instead of handler to update main thread(ie. UI). The [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) updates UI immediately without adding them into queue..